# When to use a custom stop flag over isInterrupted?

Tags: java

When would I use a stop flag and when would I use the interruption mechanic in Java to design task cancellation?

E.g.

```java
while (!cancelled)
  crawl(list.nextUrl());
```

or

```java
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
  crawl(list.nextUrl());
```

The second one has the nice advantage of working with `Executorservice.shutdownNow()`. But when should we actually use a dedicated flag?

Comment: I think that we should use custom flag when we want to pause/resume thread, or just when we have something to do when cancelling

Comment: there are only a series of methods that respond to interrupts. Also interrupts are somehow error prone, if someone forget to re-set the interrupt flag, you might be in trouble.

Comment: @Eugene That's true, if people do not propagate it from their lib it's bad. But then when I want to cancel I've basically to interrupt (for e.g. http call blocks) in my cancel method and set my flag. Else I might hang in a blocking operation for a long time. It's a pitty :(

Comment: @Regyn your http call is not going to get interrupted, it seems you miss-understand this part, to begin with.

Comment: `isInterrupted` is just flag, but it's one that can't be reset.  It's "intent", by most developers, would be for the thread to stop what it's doing and terminate as soon as possible.  So if your intention does not fall within those requirements, you should consider using your own flag - IMHO

Comment: @Eugene Well if I use a interruptible lib that supports interruption it will.

Comment: right, do you know of such?

Comment: @Eugene not from my head, but it was an example. There are IO libs out there supporting interruption. Or just imagine a lib using wait notify, I'd still like them to complete asap when I call stop

Comment: it seems you already have the answer to your question, btw. `interrupt` is easy to get wrong (especially if some callers ignore it and don't reset the flag), but if as you say you need to interrupt, there is simply no other option. A boolean flag needs to be re-checked, of course, in various places; unlike interrupts.